# How can I change the dimensions of a single cell within a cell array? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I've search quite a bit for a solution with no luck, but I believe it's because I just have some piece of syntax incorrect. In the following code snippet, the value of 'maxBlobs' is 5. The 'colCount' is a cell array of integers.

```
% create cell array with 1 row, columns = number of occurences per cell, maxBlobs # of cells
likeCent=cell(1,1,maxBlobs);  % to store like blob count centroids

for i = 1:maxBlobs % cell tracker
    val = colCount{1,1,i};% grabs number of occurences at this cell
    likeCent{1,1,i} = likeCent{1,val,i};
end
```

My goal is to change the number of columns within each cell 'i' in 'likeCent{}' from 1 to the corresponding value pulled from the 'i'th cell in 'colCount'.

Thank you!

Comment: I don’t understand what you are trying to do. `likeCent` is an 1x1x5 array. You are trying to index it with `likeCent{1,val,i}`, which will fail unless `val` is 1. I think you have a misunderstanding of the cell array. A cell array is a normal array, but the elements it stores are arrays themselves. You cannot change the size of one column of an array, you can change the size of the array, or you can change the size of the arrays contained in the cell array. To help you further, I’d need to understand better what you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ah okay, thank you for clarifying that. What I'm essentially trying to do then is have a cell array of 5 cells, which I will be filling with `val` number of empty arrays, or placeholders. So my thought process in my code was to somehow go through each cell in `likeCent` and replace it with `val` number of arrays. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Each cell contains one array, if you need `val` different arrays in each cell, you will have to collect them in a cell array. So you will be indexing `likeCent{1,1,i}{1:val}=[]`. But if all the `val` arrays are the same size, they can be a single array, which is more efficient.